# Form Submit Button - Change the action page each time submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a submit button that when pressed it emails the contents to a single email address.  The email is then manually forwarded to one of 3 people on a rota system.

Is there any way that the submit button could work so that when the first site visitor clicks it the inquiry goes to staff member 1, when the next one does it the inquiry goes to staff member 2 when the next one does it it goes to staff member 3 and then back to staff member 1 when the next one does it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If different people load the page, you need to change on server. If same client, add and read location.search or location.hash

Comment: This can be done in PHP. Create an array with the three email addresses (each with an associated id for ease of reference). Then use PHP sessions to track which id/email was last used. Then it's a simple loop: e.g last_used == 3.  If (last_used == 3) { // use #1 and set last_used to 1}

Comment: Not sure you can do that with PHP, but if you want to use something like a counter (1 => address1, 2 => address2 and so on) you can either use a database or a counter stored somewhere. However, since this is rather some server stuff, I'm not sure you can in any way understand which was the last address contacted from the client itself, that's why the database probably is a valuable solution!

Comment: For each client, diferent staff: it can be done. For example, retrieve a number stored in a DB in the server. What have you thought or tried so far?

Comment: save next email recipient to file/db, when form is submitted read file/db and email to that recipient, then update file with next recipent

Comment: This seems to be getting a little too complicated for me now.  The site doesn't actually use a database but just sends an email of the information on the form.  For example here is the form http://www.conveyancing-warehouse.com/instruct/lease-extension.html    after its been submitted the visitor is directed to -http://www.conveyancing-warehouse.com/instruct/LEASE-EXT-INSTRUCTION-MADEzf.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a column in database for current `active_member`

set `0` default value.

get first staff member from database with column `active_member` value 0

set column `active_member` to `1` when you send mail to that `staff member`.

when no member have `active_member` value column value `0` than Reset all value to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP sessions to store a server variable, for example: `next_email_recip`. *At the top of your PHP file, you will need to put:*

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['next_email_recip'])) {
    $next_email_recip = $_SESSION['next_email_recip'];
    if ($next_email_recip == 3) {
        $_SESSION['next_email_recip'] = 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['next_email_recip'] = $next_email_recip + 1;
    }
}else{
    $next_email_recip = 1;
    $_SESSION['next_email_recip'] = 2;
}
```

In your PHP code, have a simple array:

```
$arrRecips = array(
    "1" => "bob@email.com",
    "2" => "joe@email.com",
    "3" => "fred@email.com",
);
$this_time_recip = $arrRecips[$next_email_recip];
```

Comment: This is a little beyond my capabilities.  I'd be happy to pay you to implement it on our site.  My email address is wayne@qsrc.co.uk if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is store the email addresses to be used in a table (email_address_table), and each submission in a seperate table (sent_table) then everytime a visitor hits submit, before it saves and gets sent (sent_table), it checks what was the last email address that was used in (sent_table), and check which one is next in the list in the (email_address_table), saves and sent it, that way you can be sure to get an even distribution. And one step further you can add a field (off) in the (email_address_table), that way if somebody is to not use this email address again or it is dedicated and this person is off, you set the status to off, and the rotation will only happen between the remaining agent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a table and name it sent_emails. When the first email is sent enter first email address in this table. Then when second user comes and email is sent to him first check this table and if the last two records are of different email ids send to this email address. Do this for all new users like this, means before sending any mail first check their entry in this table for last two records. By creating new table you will also be able to record the time at which emails were sent.